# How to write to StdOut in Windows and FASM?

Tags: windows, stdout, intel, fasm

The question is pretty simple, yet I can't seem to find how to do it: how do I write to StdOut in Windows/FASM?

There does not seem to be any documentation online. Ideas?

Comment: not FASM, but close enough: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718332/how-can-i-do-input-output-on-a-console-with-masm

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options...

1) Use the WinAPI. This is either [WriteConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687401%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) OR by using CreateFile with the filename as CON and then using [WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

2) Using msvcrt, and [printf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc7014hz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) as you would in a c program.

Comment: The proposed WinAPI functions aren't enough, always. At least for me, I had to invoke AttachConsole(-1) once before I could write using WriteFile(GetStdHandle(-11), ...) to see the text in "cmd.exe" from which I invoked my app