# C# : Manually creating a console.writeline

Tags: c#, class, methods

I am trying to simulate the Console.Writeline manually.
i.e : i am creating a small Console Class with function WriteLine.
See my code below :

```
static class Console
{
    public static string WriteLine(string text)
    {
        return text;
    }
}
```

So i tried that with :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HiMan");
    }
}
static class Console
{
    public static string WriteLine(string text)
    {
        return text;
    }
}
```

I know that it returns the text , but how can i display it on the screen without using the Write or Writeline methods ?

I am creating this example to make people understand how classes work and why when i use WriteLine or Write() it displays the text in the console window.

Comment: If you want to know how the `Console` class works I suggest you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: You definitely can using some low level pinvoke, brb with an answer...

Comment: The correct answer to "How do classes work ?" should be language- and feature-independent. A class is a class, either in C#, Java etc. The same holds true for the concepts of inheritance, encapsulation...

Comment: Call the WriteConsole Win32 api. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7325554/1429439

Comment: So do you want your simulated console to write to the shell's buffer without using the console class?  Do you want to have your console write to a textbox on a windows form (or something other situation where you use a custom UI to just display text)?  Do you want to read input from a file and write output to a file?  Do you want to just keep track of the contents of the console in memory (in say a `string`, `stringbuilder`, or similar)?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how deep you want to go. [Console.WriteLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx) calls WriteLine on  [Console.Out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.out.aspx) internally. Console.Out is a [TextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx) that provides the WriteLine implementation. You can always implement your own WriteLine by writing bytes to the stream directly.

If you want to go deeper, such as writing to the console buffer directly, be aware that the Out, In and Error properties of Console are all redirectable and ignoring them may lead to issues, such as not being able to redirect input and output using pipes on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to do this on a fairly low level. I've used `ReadConsoleOutput` and `WriteConsoleOutput` to directly read and write the Console's display in ways that `Console.WriteLine` wouldn't let me (these are great for retro 2d console games, my original intent).

PInvoke links: [ReadConsoleOutput](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/ReadConsoleOutput.html) | [WriteConsoleOutput](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/WriteConsoleOutput.html)

You may not need the `ReadConsoleOutput`, but for those that Google this page, these methods sort of go hand in hand with each other.

If you want to read from the keyboard, *I believe* you can use `ReadConsoleInput` but I haven't actually tried that. Small grain of salt on that advice.