# Syntax errors in my assembly code from header file

Tags: assembly

I'm learning assembly code at my university. I am new to any type assembly programming. I don't understand why I'm getting the errors when i try to build. The IDE is Visual Studio 2012. The error is coming from the io.h header file. I copied the assembler directives straight from the book, so i assumed it is what the author wanted and included everything i needed.

```
; Assembler directives    
.586                ;accept instrucions for 586
.MODEL FLAT         ;generate code for flat memory
INCLUDE io.h        ;header file for input/output
.STACK 4096         ;reserve 4096-byte stack


.DATA               ;reserve storage for data
x                   DWORD               ?                                       
y                   DWORD               ?                                       
z                   DWORD               ?                                       
result              DWORD               ?                                       
prompt1             BYTE                "Enter the value for x",0               
prompt2             BYTE                "Enter the value for y",0               
prompt3             BYTE                "Enter the value for z",0               
asciiIn             BYTE                15 DUP (?)                              
msgLabel            BYTE                "The result is",0                       
msgText             BYTE                11 DUP (?),0                            

.CODE               ;start of main program code
_MainProc           PROC
                    ;read ASCII input for first number, convert to 2's comp, and
                    input               prompt1, asciiIn, 15                    
                    atod                asciiIn                                 
                    mov                 x, eax                                  

                    ;read ASCII input for second number, convert to 2's comp, an
                    input               prompt2, asciiIn, 15                    
                    atod                asciiIn                                 
                    mov                 y, eax                                  

                    ;read ASCII input for third number, convert to 2's comp, and
                    input               prompt3, asciiIn, 15                    
                    atod                asciiIn                                 
                    mov                 z, eax                                  

                    ;perform the requested calculations
                    mov                 eax, x                                  
                    add                 eax, x                                  
                    add                 eax, x                                  
                    add                 eax, x                                  
                    add                 eax, y                                  
                    add                 eax, y                                  
                    sub                 eax, z                                  
                    sub                 eax, z                                  
                    inc                 eax                                     
                    neg                 eax                                     

                    ;store the result in memory, convert from 2's comp to ASCII,
                    mov                 result, eax                             
                    dtoa                msgText, result                         
                    output              msgLabel, msgtext                       

                    mov                 eax, 0                                  
                    ret
_MainProc           ENDP                                                        
                    END
```

These are the error messages I am getting when trying to build.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: windows32, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Assembling ..\..\main.asm...
1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\io.h(1): error A2008: syntax          error : /
1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\io.h(2): error A2008: syntax error : io
1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\io.h(3): error A2008: syntax  error : *
1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\io.h(4): error A2008: syntax error : Copyright
1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\io.h(5): error A2008: syntax  error : *
1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\io.h(6): error A2008: syntax error : *
1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\io.h(7): error A2008: syntax error : *
1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\io.h(8): error A2008: syntax  error : file
1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\io.h(9): error A2008: syntax error : *
1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\io.h(10): error A2008: syntax er  ror : *
1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\io.h(11): error A2008: syntax error : *
1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\io.h(12): error A2008: syntax error : *
1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\io.h(14): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\io.h(15): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\io.h(16): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\io.h(17): error A2044: invalid character in file
```

Comment: Hmmm.... are you trying to include C header into an assembly file? This has no chance to work...

Comment: The io.h is an included header file in the framework. It supplies the code for the macros input atod etc. I should have asked why is it trying to include the c io header file?

Comment: `.h` is generally reserved for C headers. Assembler ones could use `.inc`, etc. You'd better rename it. But if it's impossible, play with include directory lists.

Comment: As others have noted, it's highly likely that `io.h` is for C programs, not assembly programs. A quick look inside the file on your part should reveal this as you should be able to tell just peering at it. Assembly include files usually end in `.inc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and it seems that io.h is (also) an assembly include file shipped with some (older) versions of MASM. It seems that the one used by modern versions of visual studio don't use them. If you intend on doing input/output in assembly, ypu will probably have to find some other means. I don't know if there is any replacement supplied with the assembler itself, but if you don't want to depend on any additional libraries, you can just [use WinAPI directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2720435/455304).

If it's too much for you, you should get interested in some additional packages like [irvine](http://kipirvine.com/asm/examples/index.htm) - you might get interested in [documentation](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html) then.

Answer (score 0):

#### See if this is your problem...

- Open the file `io.h` in your text editor
- Look on line 1, as the assembler has flagged it
- From the looks of things, my guess is that line 1 starts a C style comment (which makes good sense)
- If this is indeed the case, then you have found your problem

#### Suggested fix

- Compile `io.h` by itself; but **DO NOT** link it
- Add the names of the desired functions as `Extern` directives (use whatever syntax your particular chosen assembler wants; it appears that you are using Masm, good choice here)
- Assemble (but do not link) your assembly language file by itself
- With both files now in `OBJ` format, link them together

It's clear that you really want to learn this stuff, and an attitude like yours is welcome here, as far as I'm concerned.

I should be back in 3 or 4 hours. Others here are way smarter than I am, and they should be around with better help and answers, so let us know where you get with this.

Oh, tip for the new student from an old hand: prepare yourself in advance for another annoyance as soon as you fix this one. Do not be discouraged when it appears.  That's the way assembly is. Believe me, you'll get it. I can already tell by the way you comment your code and present your problem.